# how to get android device's NPU version

Tags: android

I found a column called "NPU Version". I tried "adb shell getprop" to get NPU Version, but failed(there's no information adout NPU Version). so my question is how could i get the NPU Version programmely?

Comment: if there's anything unclear or you want to know about, please let me know. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here's what the "NPU Version" looks like [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rCd8.jpg sorry about posting detail on the answer. i could not add image on my question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).